# create Fragment without list pane in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I am working on a Fragment application in Android 2.2. It so happens that most examples have a list on the left side that opens up a detail page when clicked.

However, does anyone know if this is by default or I can have something else other than a list like take for instance button widgets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have something else there. Note that to have the list you need to extend the ListFragment.
So you have two choices:

- Extend Fragment and do what you want. This is good if what you want does not fit into the List ideology at all.
- Extend ListFragment and use a custom Adapter. Then you can reimplement Adapter.getView and draw whatever widget you want, including the buttons.